# How to fix color flashing when generating a random color

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple web game and I'm trying to make the bricks generate random colors (not changing colors) but they keep flashing colors every millisecond.

```
    function drawBricks() {
        for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
            for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
                if (bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
                    var brickX = (c * (brickWidth + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetLeft;
                    var brickY = (r * (brickHeight + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetTop;
                    bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
                    bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
                    if (randomNumber == 1)
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";

                    if (randomNumber == 2)
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
                    
                    if (randomNumber == 3)
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF8A00";

                    if (randomNumber == 4)
                        ctx.fillStyle = "0100FF";

                    ctx.fill()
                    ctx.closePath();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If they are flashing every millisecond, it's because `drawBricks` is getting called every millisecond. You probably want to draw only once, or every second or so. You'll have to post the calling code if you want more specific details.

Comment: Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/NdJUiBFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Pastebin has the code `var interval = setInterval(draw, 10);` (line 185); `setInterval` accepts the number of *milliseconds* between executions of the provided function as its second argument - so it is trying to run it 100 times per second (every 10 milliseconds). Try changing `10` to `1000` (1 second) or a similar value.

Edit: Based on clarification of the issue in the original question, it turns out the problem was that the brick colors were being randomized every time the game scene was rendered; this seems to have been fixed by moving the randomizer out of the render loop (the `drawBricks()`) function.

Comment: This just makes the whole game run at 2 FPS. Also what I want to do is keep the bricks their random colors without changing.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your initial question - in this case, you will want to make sure the randomization function is *outside* of the render loop - otherwise you will randomize the blocks again every time the game is drawn.

Comment: Where would be the best place to put it?

Comment: It sounds like you would want to do this at the beginning and then leave the values the same from then on...so somewhere outside of `drawBricks()`

Comment: No problem! I'll edit my answer when I get a chance...